# Amazon Redshift - Copy column on the same table in batches

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, migration, amazon-redshift, database-migration

We have a large table (almost 1 billion rows). We want to change one column's type from VARCHAR to SUPER for the benefit of larger limit. Since Redshift does not support the immediate  change of column types, we have to create a new one and migrate the data from the initial column

We can't have a temp table because there is not enough space in the database. The table is almost 70 GB, hence we are looking for an update-delete or update-nullify (the old column) solution.

There is a timestamp field but the records are not unique(It is an event table)

Since it is a large table is there a way to "copy" or "migrate" this column into the SUPER one in chunks?

I haven't tries something yet because it would be bad to lose these data.

Comment: Before you go to all of the trouble of figuring out how to batch your data, I suggest that you spin up a new cluster from a snapshot and try it there. Although your overall table size may be 70 GB, Redshift stores data in a columnar format so it will only touch the data for that column (which, if it contains JSON text, could still be be a significant chunk).